# Foto de perfil no se actualiza en el lado del cliente - FFImageLoading

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin

Estoy teniendo problemas al momento de cambiar la foto de perfil del cliente; se actualiza en el lado del servidor sin ningún problema de forma inmediata, pero en el teléfono del cliente sigue apareciendo la imagen antigua por varios días a veces.

**Cabe destacar que cada vez que se da click en la imagen de perfil *(Ir a mi perfil)* ejecuto el codigo de leer la url de la imagen. Simplemente como que la ignora.**

La imagen la cargo haciendo uso del `FFImageLoading` de la siguiente forma:

```
ImageView ImgP = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgPerfilRounded);
                ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl("https://URLimage.png")
                    .LoadingPlaceholder("CargandoDifuminado", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                    .ErrorPlaceholder("CargandoDifuminado", FFImageLoading.Work.ImageSource.CompiledResource)
                    .Retry(5, 250)
                    .Into(ImgP);
```

Me imagine que puede que ser por el `.CacheDuration` que según la documentación esta configurado por defecto para 90 días, pero tampoco me deja cambiarlo ya que al hacerle referencia en el código el intellisense me dice que solo permite obtener el valor, no setearlo `{get;}`

Comment: Lo solucionaste?

Comment: Aun no, no entiendo que sucede.